# Visual studio throws exception even when "thrown" is disabled for the exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In a library I've helper functions that get an active application instance using Marshal.GetActiveObject. Problem is when I'm debugging with visual studio it breaks on/throws the following exception:

`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary`

`Additional information: Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))`

[image]

It would be expected if I did not handle the exception but in the library the exception is caught in a try...catch.

I enabled "Enable Just My Code" but it does not change anything.

So I looked for "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" but "Thrown" is already disabled. Same for "User-unhandled".

Additionnal information:

- Visual studio 12.0.40629 Update 5
- ReSharper 2016.3

Is there another option to look for or do I have a corrupted visual studio and I should reset all IDE + plugins?

Thank you.

**Edit: Code**

In Library A (which is an API of an external software): Definition of `IApplication`

In Library B (mine) :

```
public static bool TryGetRuntime(out IApplication app)
{
    try
    {
        app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("TheApplicationId") as IApplication;
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        app = null;
    }
    return app != null;
}
```

In App C:

```
IApplication app;
if (HelperClass.TryGetRuntime(out app)) {
    //do some work
}
```

Comment: That looks like an error report from the "exceptionSwallowedOnCallFromCOM" managed debugging assistant.  This MDA is normally turned off, perhaps your Debug > Exceptions > Managed Debugging Assistants configuration is not normal.  Hard to be sure with no code to look at.  Consider clicking the "Reset All" button in the dialog to put everything back to default settings.

Comment: @HansPassant I created an new app using the same code and it works fine as long as I set "Embed Interop Types" to false on the library defining the COM object. The weird thing is that the "Embed Interop Types" is not listed in library's properties in the other visual studio project. Adding the code in the post but it seems unrelated